# Using a MOSFET array to create a basic H bridge

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge

I still have this big old rc car and i wanted to make it live again since I lost the radio. I wanted to take the UPA1556AH that is inside the rc to make a H bridge and control the servo motor direction so it can turn (it is not the best idea but i don't want to wait for components). I've never created a H bridge so I'm a little confused with the schematic and the datasheet. Probably I'm very wrong. Here is the datasheet: [UPA1556AH](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/nec/UPA1556AH.pdf) and here is the H bridge was looking for: [image: Basic]
Is it possible to make it with that internal connection?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 5 FETs in the package, but 2 pairs have the sources shorted together.  You could use the single FET with one half of one pair to make an H bridge, but.....

They are all N-channel devices as well, so you would need a supply that's higher than the battery voltage to fully turn on the top side devices.

Why not find a motor driver bridge part with P-channel devices in the top and N-channel devices on the bottom?  Maybe like [this?](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/Sanken/mXqsryx.pdf)

Or maybe something along [these lines?](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvsba4e/slvsba4e.pdf?ts=1591722526786&ref_url=https://www.google.com/)

Comment: Yeah, actually I'm using a DRV8838 for the rear wheels motor from pololu. I guess they are more efficient. I can use the DRV8835 Dual Motor Driver instead of the DRV8838. Although I will need to wait for it, again :( 
Thanks ^^